# sphinxclient.h header is not found on debian

Tags: c, debian, sphinx

I'm trying to use the C client library of http://sphinxsearch.com in my project. It compiles fine on ubuntu using `libsphinxclient-dev` package

However when I try to compile it on debian sid, it complains that the header `sphinxclient.h` is missing, and I can't find any package providing this header.

Is there any "clean" way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems libsphinxclient is not included in Debian upstream and there isn't a separate package.
You can grab the deb packages from Sphinx website,libsphinxclient is installed in /usr/share/sphinxsearch/api/libsphinxclient (you might need to copy the header to include folder or add this folder to path).